# ng-bind-html data + variable correct syntax

Tags: angularjs

I can not find a way to run this thing ...
I'm using ng-bind-html to load text from a db . I would like to add a variable to one of several languages ​​. But I do not understand the correct syntax.
i'd like to use something like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="detail.txt+lang"></div>
```

where lang is a rootScope variable ("_en", "_it" and so on)
thanks

Comment: Show your code. Preferably a small example that reproduces your problem and illustrates what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
//inside the controller for the view
$scope.writeValueFromDb = function() {
    //here you can access the $rootScope
    //(after including it as a dependency in the controller)
    //and from the $rootScope object you can access the language variable
}
```

Doing this you won't have to manually pass the language variable from the `$rootScope` in every method you bind in the view.

And in the view you can bind it normally:

```
<div ng-bind-html="writeValueFromDb()"></div>
```